# PHP bbcode parser with escaping option

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-replace, bbcode

I have the function:

```
function parse_bbcode($str = ''){

    $find = array(
        "'\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]'is",
        "'\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]'is",
        "'\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]'is",
        "'\[s\](.*?)\[/s\]'is",
        "'\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]'i",
        "'\[url\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
        "'\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
        "'\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
        "'\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/link\]'i"
    );

    $replace = array(
        '<strong>\\1</strong>',
        '<em>\\1</em>',
        '<u>\\1</u>',
        '<s>\\1</s>',
        '<img src="\\1" alt="" width="100%" />',
        '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>',
        '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>',
        '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>',
        '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>'
    );

    return preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);

}
```

for parsing bbcodes.

How can I add optionality escaping for bbcodes?

Example:

Thank [b]you[/b] Mike! - Thank **you** Mike!

Thank \[b]you[/b] Mike! - Thank [b]you[/b] Mike!

Comment: BBcode is from 1998! May I ask why you are trying to reinvent the thing?

Comment: Hi Lory, why do you want to create a function on your own? Have you tried BB codes from packagist? Personally I installed a composer BB codes, and it works flawless! See: https://packagist.org/?q=bbcodes&idx=packagist&p=0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I did it!

```
function parse_bbcode($str = ''){

    $find = array(
        "'([^\\\\])\[b\](.*?)([^\\\\])\[/b\]'is",
        "'\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]'is",
        "'\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]'is",
        "'\[s\](.*?)\[/s\]'is",
        "'\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]'i",
        "'\[url\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
        "'\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
        "'\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
        "'\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
        "'([^\\\\])\\\\\['i"
    );

    $replace = array(
        '\\1<strong>\\2\\3</strong>',
        '<em>\\1</em>',
        '<u>\\1</u>',
        '<s>\\1</s>',
        '<img src="\\1" alt="" width="100%" />',
        '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>',
        '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>',
        '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>',
        '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>',
        '\\1['
    );

    return preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);

}
```

(this exaple escaping only [b] tags!)